# Paypal Overage Pricing

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using Paypal website payment subscription. I want to charge overage price from my customers when it's needed. Is that possible? I don't want to use express checkout or double modify existing subscription.

For example, I'm charging $20 each month. For only current month, I want to be able to charge $22. Still my regular payment is $20. Do I need any permission or do I need to take my customers' credit card info and use payflow sdk?

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would just need to modify the amounts you are currently setting in your subscription button.  You could set it up so that it has a 1 month trial at $20, then after that it starts its regular recurring amount of $22.

Comment: No, I don't want it. My regular payment amount is 20$. I just want it to be 22$ for only one month. Still my regular payment amount is 20$. Here, 2$ is for over usage of my service.

Comment: You would not be able to add on an additional this way Website Payments Standard subscriptions.

Comment: can it be achievable by using optional transaction amount via payflow sdk?

Comment: You would be able to do it with Payflow.  The Optional transaction would be a transaction that is processed outside of the regular recurring profile.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same question and had a call with PayPal tech support about this issue and they said there is no way to do this.  I too have a normal monthly subscription that I want to be able to charge usage overages when applicable.